# Drupal portal, create user customizable widgets on homepage

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, portal

I'd like to have opinions on how to create a structure of widgets on a portal using drupal, so that the user can customize his widgets. In particular he should be able to choose to hide or move them around, and of course the widgets will be user specific.

My question is generic, how to approach this? Is there any interesting module for drupal that might help?

Thanks

Comment: If you are able to customize blocks so that the visibility is user specific , then can the widgets be treated as blocks ?

Comment: yes that should be possible. I'd have to build some UI based on some javascript library and then some custom php integration to save the preferences in drupal database then?

Answer (score 0):

Panels module should help : http://drupal.org/project/panels

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Dashboard module](http://drupal.org/project/dashboard) or the [Homebox module](http://drupal.org/project/homebox).  Both of these allow for custom "dashboards" that users can customize with "widgets".